# Finding the closure of $\{ \frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ in finite complement topology on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Please point out where I am making a mistake:

> Let $\mathscr T$ be a finite complement topology of $\mathbb R$. Let K be defined as, $K= \{ \frac1n \mid n \in \mathbb N \}$.
>
> **I need to find the closure of $K$.**
>
> Let $B_n = \{ \frac1n \} , \, n \in \mathbb N $. So $B_n \subset \mathbb R$. Let us define $U_n = \mathbb R \setminus B_n$. We can check that $U_n$ is open in $\mathscr T$ because $\mathbb R \setminus U_n =B_n$ is finite.
>
> $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} U_n = \mathbb R \setminus K \implies \mathbb  R \setminus K $ is open $.\implies K$ is closed. $\implies \overline K = K$.

But $\overline K$ should be equal to $\mathbb R$!

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake you made is the calculation $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}U_n$. This set is actually $\mathbb R$, since even $U_1\cup U_2 = \mathbb R$

Hint: What do all closed set (except for $\mathbb R$) in the finite compliment topology have in common?

Comment: All finite subsets of $\mathbb R$ (except for $\mathbb R$) are closed in finite compliment topology, isn't it?

Comment: That statement is slightly clumsy. It seems you want to say that $\mathbb R$ is not closed. The point is not that all finite subsets are closed (they are, but it's not important). The point is that all closed sets, except for $\mathbb R$, are finite.

Comment: I know that that $\mathbb R$ is closed. and yes by definition of finite compliment topology , your statement that 'all closed sets (except for $\mathbb R$), are finite' makes more sense. I got my mistake in calculating union. but still I dont know why $\bar K = \mathbb R$??

Comment: All closed sets except for $\mathbb R$ are finite. The closure  of $K$ is by definition a set that contains $K$. What can you say about the number of elements in $\bar K$?

Comment: Since $K$ is denumerable, there are infinite number of elements in $K \implies$ there are infinite number of elements in $\bar K$.

Comment: You're almost there. You know that $\bar K$ is an infinite set. By definition, it is also closed. What do you know of infinite closed sets in your topology?

Comment: $\mathbb R$ is the only infinite closed set. So $\bar K$ has to be equal to $\mathbb R$. right?

Comment: If $\bar K = \mathbb R$ then any open neighborhood around $x \in \mathbb R$ should intersect $K$. Now suppose i choose $x=-5$ and $U(x)= (- \infty , -4) \cup (2, \infty)$. Now $U(x)$ is open but $U(x)$ doesnt intersect with $K$??

Comment: Correct. So the proof goes: $\bar K$ is closed by definition. $\bar K$ has an infinite amount of elements. The only infinite closed set is $\mathbb R$. Therefore, $\bar K = \mathbb R$.

Comment: @5xum Small note: I like *compliments*, but you are dealing here with *complements*.

Comment: @RichardJ your $U(x)$ is not open. Why would it be open? Does it have a finite complement?

Comment: Oh!!! I think now I understood it fully. I was making this huge mistake consistently. yes $U(x)$ is not open. Thanx a lot :)

Comment: I think you are mixing the terms "finite" and "bounded". See, for your $U(x)$, the complement of $U$ is $[-4, 2]$, which is a bounded set in standard topology, however, this does not apply in your topology. What matters in your topology is if there are a finite number of elements in $U$, and you can easily see that that is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

In a finite complement topology on $X$ sets are closed iff they are finite or coincide with $X$.